# If $A⊂B$, can I assume that there exists an injective function $A\to B$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could I say that there exists a function $f\colon A\to B$, where $f(x)=x \in B$?

Comment: Yes, you can.${}{}$

Comment: The injection morphism is the simplest.

Comment: I wouldn't say "assume" is the correct verb here. You can *prove* that the function $f:A\to B$ defined as $f(x)=x$ is injective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply take $f:A\to B$ define by $f(x)=x$.